# using d3.js as an external in webpack

Tags: d3.js, webpack

I'm using [this tutorial](http://jslog.com/2014/10/02/react-with-webpack-part-1/) to setup a React.js project with webpack. The webpack.config.js below is almost an exact copy (except that I'm using an `app` and 'dist' folder), and I am also adding d3.js as an `external`. Because React is added as an `external` it lets me do `require('react')` in any of my app files without including it in the bundle. I wish to do the same with `d3.js` and have installed it as a node_module, and listed it in the externals area of my webpack config, but when I do `require('d3')` i get an error message that it's not available.

How can I use `d3` (or jQuery for that matter) as an external if I have it installed as a node_module?

this is my project setup

```
/app
/dist
/node_modules
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

> ```
> module.exports = {
>     entry: './app/index.jsx',
>     output: {
>         path: './dist',
>         filename: 'bundle.js', //this is the default name, so you can skip it
>         //at this directory our bundle file will be available
>         //make sure port 8090 is used when launching webpack-dev-server
>         publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets'
>     },
>     module: {
>         loaders: [
>             {
>                 //tell webpack to use jsx-loader for all *.jsx files
>                 test: /\.jsx$/,
>                 loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony'
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     externals: {
>         //don't bundle the 'react' npm package with our bundle.js
>         //but get it from a global 'React' variable
>
>         'react': 'React',
>         'd3': 'd3'
>     },
>     resolve: {
>         modulesDirectories: ['app', 'node_modules'],
>         extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 20):

I know this question has been open a while, but hopefully this answer is still useful!

If you have installed d3 (or jQuery) as a node_module, you can use the webpack ProvidePlugin to tie an arbitrary key to a module.

The key will be then be available to require anywhere in your webpack app.

E.g. **webpack.config.js**

```
{
 ...lots of webpack config here...
 ...
 plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        d3: 'd3',
        $: 'jquery'
    })
 ]
 ...
}
```

Then in **my-file.js**

`var d3 = require('d3')`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you help me find the answer to this very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912988/how-to-load-c3js-properly-into-webpack ?