# How to load C3JS properly into WebPack?

Tags: node.js, d3.js, webpack, vue.js, c3.js

I am trying to use C3JS, which is a library based on D3JS in my VUEJS/WebPack project ([created from this boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)).

I load D3JS by npm installing it and by loading it as a webpack plugin like anything else. However, doing the same for C3JS does not work.

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery', // <--- This works, I can call this variable anywhere in my JS code
      jQuery: 'jquery', // <--- This works...
      d3: 'd3', // <--- This works...
      c3: 'c3' // <--- This DOES NOT work, I can import c3 but the CSS is not loaded
    })
  ],
```

I tried to find some pattern but no luck...

For example D3JS has the following folder structure:

[image]

While C3JS has the following:

[image]

[This is D3JS.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3)

[This is C3JS.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c3)

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Since webpack treats everything as a module you can also `import 'path/to/c3/style.css`. You can also use `require` syntax as well.